# Can somebody give me a concrete example of a callback function in C?

Tags: c, callback

Writing a Queue library in C for a school project. I am having trouble understanding how to implement a callback function in main() to test the library. Would anyone be able to provide the general steps to do this?

What is the syntax of a callback function declaration?

Comment: You do not implement any function in main(). C does not have nested functions.You need to implement your callback like any other function. There is no special syntax.

Comment: callback: [`qsort()` 4th argument](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/qsort.html)

Answer (score 0):

With a *call-back* function, you call your library and then the library calls you back, for example for more information, to ask to proceed with some computation or to inform you of some progress.

So what the callback function is or looks like depends on what your library wants to do.

- call your library function `f()` with a pointer to your function
- library does some things and then calls your function
- you do something and return
- your library function continues
- your library function finally returns to you.

So you must write your callback function and then pass the function pointer to your library, for example:

```
int f(int prm1, int (*g)(void));
```

This defines your library function `f` to have two parameters, an int and a pointer to a function taking no parameters and returning int. Now you write your function:

```
int myCallBack(void)
{
    // do something
    return 1;
}
```

and now you can call your library function `f`:

```
f(123, myCallBack);
```

Comment: Thanks! - When I call myCallBack in f, why wouldn't I need to pass in a pointer to that function, but instead just calling it?

Comment: I’m not 100% sure of what you’re asking, but I think the answer is that you’re not calling myCallBack in the call to f, you’re passing it’s address...